# How to call a method of other class from Static void main in c# console application?

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

I want to call the `GetDataTabletFromCSVFile` method from the `PRogram` class, but when I try to create an instance of the `ReadCSV` class, I am getting this error: `Type or name space could not be Found`

Here is my code below:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ReadCSV r = new ReadCSV();
    }
}

public class ReadCSV
{
    //reading data from CSV files
    public static DataTable GetDataTabletFromCSVFile(string csv_file_path) 
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: The intended member is static,  so no instance is needed `DataTable table = ReadCSV.GetDataTabletFromCSVFile("path")`

Comment: Code shown in the post does not produce the error you claim it does. Please read [MCVE] guidance on posting code.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to create an instance for static methods. You can directly access the static members by using the class name itself.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DataTable Tbl = ReadCSV.GetDataTabletFromCSVFile(path);
    }
}

public class ReadCSV
{
    //reading data from CSV files
    public static DataTable GetDataTabletFromCSVFile(string csv_file_path)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `static` keyword in C# entirely changes the behavior of the type/member you are declaring it with.

Below is from the [Microsoft .NET Documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static)

> Use the static modifier to declare a static member, which belongs to the type itself rather than to a specific object.

This explains how `static` methods don't require an instance to be declared before they are called. An easy way to think about it is that `static` is instead using the `type` declaration as a `namespace` rather than an `object` member.

The code below could be used to achieve the results you desire:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Using command line arguments here would be a good idea.
        string path = "Some/Random/Directory/File.csv";

        var dataTable = ReadCSV.GetDataTabletFromCSVFile(path);

        //Now do something with dataTable...
    }
}

//It would be a good idea to declare the class as static also.
public static class ReadCSV
{
    //reading data from CSV files
    public static DataTable GetDataTabletFromCSVFile(string csv_file_path)
    {
        //You will also need to return something here.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you must declare static class ReadCSV. to use static method, its class must be static

```
public static class ReadCSV
{
    //reading data from CSV files
    public static DataTable GetDataTabletFromCSVFile(string csv_file_path)
    {
        //You will also need to return something here.
    }
}
```

and in main

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DataTable Tbl = ReadCSV.GetDataTabletFromCSVFile(path);
    }
}
```